# Writing excel formulae that reference columns by number rather than letter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible, and if so what is the syntax, to write formulae in Excel using the column's integer number rather than the lettering system that is the default?  I know it is possible to change the way that column IDs display but I am not sure how to put this into practice with regards to writing formulae.

For instance, if I wanted C1 to be A1+B1, but I wanted to write this with numbers instead of letters, obviously it couldn't be 11+21 - excel will just give me 32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try R1C1 style references.

More info here:

https://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/

Quoting from that webpage:

> First, the familiar A1 style:
>
> [image: A1 style]
>
> And now for R1C1….
>
> [image: R1C1 style]

Absolute references...

> In R1C1, there are no $. If I write R3C4 I am referring to $D$3. So if there are no brackets, it’s an absolute reference. This makes partial absolute references easier to enter too.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the Excel setting to use R1C1, then the formula is

=RC[-2]+RC[-1]

In R1C1 notation, the row is identified by the R and the column by the C value.

`=R1C1` is an absolute address to Row 1, Column 1

`=R[1]C[1]` is a relative address. Starting from the current cell it goes 1 row down and 1 column to the right. The square brackets determine the offset. This can be a negative number if the offset is above or to the left of the current cell.

For more information about this topic, check the Excel help for `r1c1 reference style`.

If you want to keep the A1 notation and use a number to identify a column, then you can use a combination with Index.

=INDEX(1:1,1)+INDEX(1:1,2)

Comment: +1 for finally a solution to this without switching to `R1C1`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to switch Excel over to the R1C1 reference style.  It'll be in your Options menu (pro tip: tag or list what version of Excel you're using and we can give better answers).

Once that's on, the general syntax is...

Absolute References:

```
R1C1 = A1  
R4C7 = G4  
R14C25 = Y14
```

Relative References (Assume your active cell is B4/R4C2)

```
R[1]C = R5C2 / B5 (down 1 row)  
R[-1]C = R3C2 / B3 (up 1 row)  
RC[1] = R4C3 / C4 (right 1 column)  
RC[-1] = R4C2 / A4 (left 1 column)
```

Formulas work just like you'd expect them to:
Add 2 cells:  `=R1C1 + R1C2` is the same as `=A1 + B1`
Add 2 cells to the left (assuming you are in A3/R3C1): `=R1C[-1] + R1C[-2]` is the same as `=B1 + A1`